# How to initializate service from component?

Tags: angular, angular8

I use separate instanse of service in each componnents:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-orders',
    templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders.component.scss'],
    providers: [PaginationService],
})
```

Service pagination is:

```
@Injectable()
export class PaginationService {
    private offset: number;
    private limit: number;

    constructor() {
        this.offset = 0;
        this.limit = 20;
    }
  }
```

As you can see service has initialization in constructor.
How to initializate service from specific component like:

```
providers: [PaginationService(0, 20)],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a factory provider, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PaginationService,
      useFactory: () => new PaginationService(0, 20)
    }
  ],
})
```

You can find more samples in the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers).

Comment: Type '{ PaginationService: typeof PaginationService; useFactory: () => PaginationService; }' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'PaginationService' does not exist in type 'Provider'

Comment: "{ PaginationService: typeof PaginationService; useFactory: () => PaginationService; }" this is the error message? On the useFactory arrow function is missing the "new" keyword. I will make an stackblitz sample.

Comment: I still get the same error:

`    providers: [{ PaginationService, useFactory: () => new PaginationService(0, 20) }, ApplicationService],`

Comment: sorry I forgot `provide`

Comment: I have updated the sample to use multiples components: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e2hbwj

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to inject the service as normal, then in your component's constructor you could call a method on the service that performs setup with the values provided, something along the lines of:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-orders',
    templateUrl: './orders.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./orders.component.scss']
})
export class OrdersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private paginationService: PaginationService) {
    this.paginationService.setup(0, 20);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `InjectionToken` for them.

*injection.tokens.ts*

```
import { InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";

export const PAGINATION_OFFSET = new InjectionToken<string>('PaginationOffset');
export const PAGINATION_LIMIT = new InjectionToken<string>('PaginationLimit');
```

*component.ts*

```
import {PAGINATION_OFFSET, PAGINATION_LIMIT} from "<injection.tokens>"

    @Component({
      selector: 'stackoverflow',
      template: ``,
      styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
      providers: [
        PaginationService,
        {
          provide: PAGINATION_OFFSET,
          useValue: 10
        },
        {
          provide: PAGINATION_LIMIT,
          useValue: 50
        }
      ]
    })
```

*pagination.service*

```
   import {PAGINATION_OFFSET, PAGINATION_LIMIT} from "./injection-tokens";
    
    @Injectable()
    export class PaginationService {
      constructor(@Inject(PAGINATION_OFFSET) private offset: number, @Inject(PAGINATION_LIMIT) private limit: number ) {}
}
```

You can check working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x298vq)

Comment: Why `('PaginationOffset');` and using on uppercase PAGINATION_OFFSET,

Comment: Whats values should be here ('PaginationOffset')?

Comment: It creares new injection with unique string. You can change or override. Also, it's uppercase because you can't inject it directly. It's not a service or something, just globally const token.